# Sanity Error: `dataset` must be provided to perform queries with React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dataset, sanity

I'm trying to create a blog with Sanity CMS; when I try to get data from Sanity database i get that

"Error: `dataset` must be provided to perform queries"

I got client.js component with projectID and database name

the component that gives me error looks like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import sanityClient from "../client.js";
export default function AllPosts() {
  const [allPostsData, setAllPosts] = useState(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    sanityClient
      .fetch(
        `*[_type == "post"]{
        title,
        slug,
        mainImage{
          asset->{
          _id,
          url
        }
      }
    }`
      )
      .then((data) => setAllPosts(data))
      .catch(console.error);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Blog Posts</h2>
      <h3>Welcome to my blog posts page!</h3>
      <div>
        {allPostsData &&
          allPostsData.map((post, index) => (
            <Link to={"/" + post.slug.current} key={post.slug.current}>
              <span key={index}>
                <img src={post.mainImage.asset.url} alt="" />
                <span>
                  <h2>{post.title}</h2>
                </span>
              </span>
            </Link>
          ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Used the same tutorial, and encountered the same error. Under "client.js", make sure that database is set to "production".

Answer (score 2):

For me, the issue was I spelled dataset: "dataSet".
No Camel case here folks, use: "dataset: 'production',

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32165339)

Answer (score 1):

In my case the mistake was in the API version property inside Client.js
I  cchanged it to 2022-02-01 and it worked perfectly fine for me. Don't know exactlywas is the reason for this, but still, it got the problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Check your client.js file. I had the same error before realizing that I spelt **dateset** instead of **dataset**